# Material-Ui Grid How can I achive styling 3 columns with 2 cards in each column like in the desired picture?

Tags: typescript, material-ui, flexbox, grid

I am trying to style 3 columns with 2 cards in each column. Each card holds multiple fields. The desired outcome looks like this: [image: desired outcome]

And now here is my page:
[image: my actual page]

As you can see my page is not properly styled like in the desired outcome.
Here is the code with the full styles:

```
> return (
    <Grid container spacing={2}>
      <ServiceDescriptionHeader />
      <GeneralGrid container spacing={2} item xs={12}>
        <FirstColumn sx={classes.firstColumn} xs={4}>
          <Contact title={t('contact')} sx={classes.input} xs={12}>
            <GeneralPerson
              sx={classes.gridItem}
              value={data.general_contact_person || ''}
              onChange={(value) =>
                updateFieldValue('general_contact_person', value)
              }
              label={t('generalContact')}
              type='text'
              variant={'outlined'}
            />
            <Representative
              sx={classes.gridItem}
              label={t('representative')}
              type='text'
              variant={'outlined'}
              value={data.representative || ''}
              onChange={(value) => updateFieldValue('representative', value)}
            />
          </Contact>
          <OtherPersons
            title='Other Authorized Persons'
            sx={classes.input}
            xs={6}
          >
            <Accordion>
              <AccordionSummary
                expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                aria-controls='other-auth-content'
                id='other-auth-header'
              ></AccordionSummary>
              <AccordionDetails>
                <Typography>
                  Further authorizations can only be assigned after the service
                  description has been created.
                </Typography>
              </AccordionDetails>
            </Accordion>
          </OtherPersons>
        </FirstColumn>
        <SecondColumn sx={classes.secondColumn}>
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
    <Grid item xs={12}></Grid>
          <TotalProject
            title={t('totalProjectDurationandProjectAssignment')}
            sx={classes.input}
            xs={12}
          >
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <StartDate
                  xs={12}
                  sx={classes.gridItem}
                  label={t('startDate')}
                  maxDate={data.end_date || null}
                  value={data.start_date || ''}
                  onChange={(newDate) =>
                    updateFieldValue('start_date', newDate)
                  }
                  locale={dayjs.locale()}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <EndDate
                  sx={classes.gridItem}
                  label={t('endDate')}
                  value={data.end_date || ''}
                  onChange={(newDate) => updateFieldValue('end_date', newDate)}
                  locale={dayjs.locale()}
                  minDate={data.start_date || null}
                />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <TGTENumber
                  sx={classes.gridItem}
                  label={t('tgteNumber')}
                  value={data.TG_TE_number || ''}
                  type='text'
                  variant={'outlined'}
                  onChange={(value) => updateFieldValue('TG_TE_number', value)}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <Budget
                  sx={classes.gridItem}
                  label={t('budget')}
                  value={data.budget || ''}
                  type='text'
                  variant='outlined'
                  onChange={(value) => updateFieldValue('budget', value)}
                />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </TotalProject>
          </Grid>
          <Description title={t('description')} sx={classes.input} xs={9}>
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
              <Grid xs={4}>
                <ShortTitle
                  sx={classes.gridItem}
                  label={t('shorttitle')}
                  value={data.short_title || ''}
                  type='text'
                  variant='outlined'
                  onChange={(value) => updateFieldValue('short_title', value)}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid xs={4}>
                <ShortDescription
                  sx={classes.gridItem}
                  label={t('shortdescription')}
                  value={data.short_description || ''}
                  type='text'
                  variant='outlined'
                  onChange={(value) =>
                    updateFieldValue('short_description', value)
                  }
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid xs={4}>
                <Comment
                  sx={classes.gridItem}
                  label={t('comments')}
                  value={data.comment || ''}
                  type='text'
                  variant='outlined'
                  onChange={(value) => updateFieldValue('comment', value)}
                />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Description>
        </SecondColumn>
        <Grid >
          <ThirdColumn sx={classes.thirdColumn}>
            <DepartmentsCosts
              title={t('departmentandCosts')}
              sx={classes.input}
              xs={12}
            >
              <Deparment
                sx={classes.gridItem}
                id='deparments-label'
                title={t('departments')}
                labelId='deparments'
                label={'deparments'}
                variant='outlined'
                value={data.department}
                onChange={(value) => updateFieldValue('department', value)}
                items={deparmentsItems}
              />
              <Cost
                sx={classes.gridItem}
                id='deparments-label'
                title={t('cost')}
                labelId='deparments'
                label={'deparments'}
                variant='outlined'
                value={data.department}
                onChange={(value) => updateFieldValue('department', value)}
                items={CostsItems}
              />
              <ClientLocation
                sx={classes.gridItem}
                id='deparments-label'
                title={t('clientLocation')}
                labelId='deparments'
                label={'deparments'}
                variant='outlined'
                value={data.department}
                onChange={(value) => updateFieldValue('department', value)}
                items={LocationItems}
              />
            </DepartmentsCosts>
            <DocumentationReport
              title={t('documentationandReports')}
              sx={classes.input}
              xs={8}
            >
              <Documentation
                sx={classes.gridItem}
                label={t('documentation')}
                value={data.documentation || ''}
                type='text'
                variant='outlined'
                onChange={(value) => updateFieldValue('documentation', value)}
              />
              <Report
                sx={classes.gridItem}
                label={t('report')}
                value={data.report || ''}
                type='text'
                variant='outlined'
                onChange={(value) => updateFieldValue('report', value)}
              />
              <Grid container spacing={2}>
                <Grid item xs={12} sx={classes.gridItem}>
                  <Typography>
                    A project report will be submitted at the latest
                  </Typography>
                  <Grid sx={classes.typo}>
                    <Submited
                      label=''
                      sx={classes.textField}
                      value={data.submited || ''}
                      type='text'
                      variant='outlined'
                      onChange={(value) => updateFieldValue('submited', value)}
                    />
                    <Typography>weeks after the end of the project.</Typography>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </DocumentationReport>
          </ThirdColumn>
        </Grid>
      </GeneralGrid>
    </Grid>
  );
};
 
export const classes: SxPropsElementsInterface = {
  input: {
    width: '100%',
    marginTop: '40px',
    marginBottom: '10px',
    paddingTop: '15px',
    paddingRight: '15px',
    padding: '10px',
  },
  main: {
    display: 'flex',
    height: '75px',
    marginLeft: '10px',
    marginRight: '10px',
    paddingRight: '15px',
  },
  gridItem: {
    padding: '10px',
    marginLeft: '15px',
      },
  firstColumn: {
   flex: '1',
   paddingRight: '10px',
   paddingLeft: '10px',
  },
  secondColumn: {
    flexGrow: '1',
    paddingRight: '10px',
   },
   thirdColumn: {
    flexGrow: '1',
    paddingLeft: '10px',
   },
   textField: {
    width: '90px',
    marginBottom: '5px',
    marginRight: '10px',
   },
   typo: {
    display: 'flex', 
    alignItems: 'center', 
    marginTop: '5px',
  },
};
```

In the picture the Cards for a specific column are alligned and below each other and they take space which for my code, for some reason I can't make them take more space.